# sql query for retrieving data from two tables

Tags: sql, select, join

There are two tables as below

employee table: `empid, empname, deptid`

department table: `deptid, deptname`

then write query to "list all employees for dept name=computer"

Answer (score 3):

this should be pretty straight forward,

```
SELECT  a.empid, a.empname, b.deptname
FROM    employee a
        INNER JOIN department b
            ON a.deptid = b.deptid
ORDER   BY  b.deptname, a.empname
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba05b/3)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thanks this helps me learn the inner join clause Although tried a lot but was fitting into my mind the Join clauses etc

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT empname, deptname 
from employee, department
where employee.deptid=department.deptid
and department.deptname='computer';
```

Computer must be case sensitive as per your values in your table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.empname, deptname
FROM employee e
    INNER JOIN department d
    ON e.deptid = d.deptid
GROUP BY emptname, deptname
```